# Динамический запрос

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица со следующими данными:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нужно сделать так чтобы алгоритм подсчитывал количество часов лабораторных, лекций, семинаров. Попробовал реализовать все это через if else. Алгоритм работает, и все подсчитывает.

```
$bd = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list WHERE group='ПМ11' discipline='Информатика'");
            while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($bd)) {
            $res = $myrow['type'];
            if ($res == 'Лекция') {
                //Часов лекций
                $lec = $myrow['count_hours'];

                //Количество студентов в группе
                $countstudents = $myrow['count_students'];
            }

            if ($res == 'Семинар') {
             //Часов семинаров
            $seminar = $myrow['count_hours'];
            }

            if ($res == 'Лабораторная') {
                //Часов лабораторных
                $lab = $lab + $myrow['count_hours'];
                //Количество подгрупп
                $countpodgroup++;
            }

            }
}
```

Но только для одной группы и одного предмета, так как я задал это в условии. А в базе множество разных групп, и у каждой группы несколько предметов. Как мне сделать так чтобы в условие запроса подставлялись остальные группы из БД(в моем случае следующая группа - ПМ12), и алгоритм обнулял все значения переменных которые были использованы ранее, и по новой рассчитывал для следующей группы...Как то структуру выборки поменять. PDO к примеру использовать как мне часто советуют.

Comment: сделайте сначала запрос на получение всех групп,что то вроде SELECT DISTINCT group FROM list ,и по результатам этого запроса сделайте цикл,в который вложите тот,что у вас уже есть, подставляя найденные группы

Comment: @Shorty это не совсем то. Данные те же, но задача уже совсем другая

Comment: @Darth т.е сначала я вывожу в цикле все существующие в базе группы. А потом в этом цикле я использую тот, что приведен выше. подставляя в условие запроса поочередно элементы массива. Но как быть с предметами? У одной группы может быть много предметов(Информатика, Проектирование, Моделирование и т.д.) Их тоже нужно как то учитывать в цикле.

Answer (score 1):

Посчитать количество часов по каждой группе

```
SELECT *, sum(count_hours) FROM list GROUP BY 'group'
```

Количество часов по каждой группе и предмету

```
SELECT *, sum(count_hours) FROM list GROUP BY 'group', 'type'
```

А вообще, не поленись и изучи агрегатные функции. Хотя бы [отсюда](http://www.sql.ru/docs/sql/u_sql/ch6.shtml). Это очень мощный и полезный инстумент в sql. 
Это сэкономит много тебе много времени *и репутации на stackoverflow.*

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку вопрос является дублем и уже имеет ответ, я напишу еще раз только сам принцип, которого ты не понимаешь, из-за чего происходят все твои проблемы:

**СЧИТАТЬ ДОЛЖНА БАЗА ДАННЫХ**

Все подсчеты должны быть сделаны с помощью SQL.

Считать что-либо в скрипте - это варварство и дикость.
Если считаешь в скрипте, то тогда вообще откажись от компьютера, и веди список на листке бумаги, а сумму считай на счетах. Потому что твой подход придуман именно для таких технологий, а базу данных ты использовать не хочешь.

PDO к твоим проблемам отношения не имеет. Это просто набор функций, которые отправляют твой запрос В БД и позволяют получить результат меньшим количеством кода. Такой же набор, как и устаревшие mysql_*. Ты должен пользоваться PDO по той же причине, по которой должен мыть руки перед едой. Не важно, что ты собрался есть - руки мыть все равно надо. Так и здесь: неважно, какие данные ты собрался получать, и какая вообще задача стоит. Просто решать её надо через ПДО. При том, что ПДО сама по себе никакие вычисления не делает. Она просто посылает запрос в БД.

По конкретно этой задаче:
Точно так же, как и в предыдущей, надо использовать группировку, оператор GROUP BY. В котором можно перечислить несколько полей через запятую. Но сначала нужно определиться с форматом получаемых данных, а ты, по-моему, сам слабо себе представляешь, какие данные и в каком формате хочешь получить.

Comment: формат данных конечно же числовой.